# Excel - Copy the Cells of One Column to a New Column Excluding Any Cells with a String Length <= 1 without VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel

Are there a set of Excel functions that would allow me to Copy the Cells of One Column to a New Column Excluding Any Cells with a String Length <= 1 without using VBA?

Assume the number of rows in the input column could be in excess of 100,000.

Answer (score 3):

Found it, use this in a new cell such as F1.

```
=FILTER(E1:E305615,LEN(E1:E305615)>1)
```

Comment: +1 from me, I actually prefer your answer to mine

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IF for this. assuming orginal column is A then use the below and drag down.

```
=IF(LEN(A1)<=1,"",A1)
```

This will differ to using FILTER in that you will get a blank cell where the LEN is 1 char long, just wanted to provide an alternative for anyone using an older version of Excel.

Comment: +1 for Excel compatibility